How should First Answers that are basically "never mind, I realized my question was invalid" be reviewed?
I occasionally run into questions like this one in the "First Answers" queue. The question is a good, high-effort question (for a new user), but the answer (posted by the original asker) is basically just "I realized that my question was invalid, so never mind." How should this be reviewed in the First Answers queue?
Some things that come to mind:

The question nor the answer are low-effort and therefore I'm hesitant to "penalize" a new user with a closure or flag.
This isn't a case of just the asker answering their own question - I already know that's fine and encouraged. This is the asker self-identifying their own question as being invalid, and therefore not useful to others.
At the same time, the question is not a "useful artifact" to keep around. I'm being asked to review the answer, not the question, though. What, if anything, should I do with the answer review?

Thanks for any insights from the more experienced moderators around here!

The issue shouldn't have been raised using the answer option. It's not an answer. It doesn't (attempt to) answer the question; it gives additional incidental context for the question, which information-wise is completely useless for other users, and as such goes against our site's policy.
You can flag it as such. Especially for new users it's nice to point out what's wrong with it, though, and you can link to a relevant subsection of the Help pages (e.g. I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?).
The next part is to assess the actual validity of the question. That the OP doesn't find it important or pertinent anymore doesn't mean it it is no longer useful. If the author doesn't give a good reason as to why the question is invalidated, you can ask after it in a comment.
If the author expands on it, and the question is actually invalidated, you can urge them to delete their question altogether, so it doesn't have to go through review queues.
If their reasons are insufficient to invalidate the question, it can remain open (if they don't mind).

That OP originally did add that info to their question. But a Python expert (who is a very active curator) advised them to post the info in the form of a self-answer instead.

@PM2Ring Strange, because that kind of information is not what answers are for. But things might be run a little different on your site, so I'd suggest asking on its meta site as well.

I considered that it was a valid answer because the question boiled down to "Q. why is this input invalid? A. The API doesn't accept integers here, only strings". Which, given that the error message is the result of a TypeError falling through from deep internal logic (and not any explicit checking by the API), is a reasonable beginner-level question. While the cited example in the documentation exclusively uses strings, it doesn't make clear that this is a requirement. Plenty of third-party APIs would automatically convert inputs to string in an analogous situation.

(Correction: it was an AttributeError, but still one logically caused by an incorrect data type.)


This is the asker self-identifying their own question as being invalid, and therefore not useful to others.

Invalid questions aren't necessarily useless to others. If a question was asked, it represents a misunderstanding. If this is a common misunderstanding, a frame challenge answer could useful to others.
Depending on the nature of the misunderstanding, you might encourage the user to write up an explanation of why the question is invalid. What did they realise, that led them to believe it's not a valid question? Perhaps point them towards How to write a nice frame challenge?, or other resources on the subject.

This is good advice in general, but "frame challenges" are, I would say, typically not compatible with questions that are on topic for Stack Overflow.

Here is how I suggest you handle such cases:
Flag the answer as 'not an answer'.
Then, review the question.  Is it useful to others?  Is it clear and does it stand alone?  If so, leave it be.  But if there are problems with the question that make it not suitable here, it might be appropriate to also vote to close the question.

I was directly involved in the example case, so I should weigh in here.
In general, I agree with Joachim: phrases like this indicate a non-answer to a question that should have been closed in the first place. But in this particular case it's as MisterMiyagi says - the answer you cite wasn't just "I realized that my question is invalid", but included an explanation of the actual issue. My assessment was that, after a full investigation, there was a suitable underlying question and that OP had determined a correct answer. Originally, this was edited into the question, so I said to write an answer instead.
To expand a bit - and apologies in advance to the non-programming audience for any confusion - originally the question reported a complete error message and clear description of a problem and context, but didn't have a proper minimal reproducible example (MRE). It just showed the one line of code where the error was reported (which actually was misleading because of both how Python works and how the library implemented the feature). I cast a close vote and left a comment to try to help the OP fix the question. (Nobody else seems to have paid attention, so the question didn't get closed during this whole process).
I made at least two mistakes there: I didn't actually look at the linked example in the documentation, and I didn't insist on the MRE before offering further advice. Based on the depth and complexity of the stack trace, and taking OP's claim at face value that the example was simply copied from documentation (this turned out not to be the case - the input was modified in an invalid way), I gave the hypothesis that there could be a bug in the library which should be reported to the library authors - and I suggested that before linking the MRE guidance.
OP apparently took that at face value, and ended up getting the problem solved by the library authors. In short, this isn't considered a bug and the input format had to be fixed. Then this information was edited into the question, and I said that it had to be written as an answer instead. I arguably made a third mistake here, by not giving proper guidance on how to write a self-answer to a question (the Help Center documentation isn't very... helpful here). So I didn't consider the effect that a literal cut-and-paste of the answer edit would have on the First Answers queue. But I can only anticipate so much.
However, OP also provided the MRE I asked for. This invalidated the original error stack trace (since the code was no longer using tkinter), but an error message was at least provided for the new code. As it turns out, a detailed stack trace is not really needed to understand the problem. (we generally ask for a complete error on Stack Overflow for these kinds of problems, but editors with subject matter expertise can trim this at their discretion.)
At this point I retracted my close vote because:

I intended to edit the question and answer afterwards to clean up.

It appeared that there was a valid beginner-level issue here: the error message wasn't explicitly created by the library, but just a natural consequence of it receiving unexpected input, so it didn't give clear guidance. (This is very common for third-party Python libraries; there are standard intuitions that more experienced programmers have about fixing those kinds of things, but it's not practical to package that information into the Q&A format.)

Upon consulting the documentation, the requirements for the input (basically: strings only, no integers etc.) weren't explicit: the example uses only strings, and even gives examples of integral numbers expressed as strings rather than integers, but documentation authors really shouldn't expect their users to make those kinds of inferences. It would have been acceptable per Stack Overflow policy to repeat explicit information from the documentation anyway; but this raised my confidence that the problem was not a "typo" - i.e., the OP had a clear reason to expect the malformed input to work, and was deliberate in providing it.


I stand by this assessment, so I have now edited the question and answer per my plan.

Shouldn't this be posted on SO's meta? Your answer (and that of MisterMiyagi) is about the specific circumstances of the example, not the generic situation sketched by the OP in their question here, which is IMHO not really helpful for Meta.

@Joachim the question was posted here, because it applies network-wide (other sites have a First Answers queue). Because a concrete example was provided, it's important to show the extenuating circumstances of that example - because it helps people understand, network-wide, the nuance in the policy (other sites have analogous reasons for closure, and every site should be concerned with whether the question actually is invalid, and not just with whether the OP thinks that's the case).

Good point. I stand informed :)

You should review answers for what they are, not some imagined versions.

I realized that my question was invalid, so never mind.

This is not what the example answer shows. That something isn’t a bug in a library doesn’t make a question about it invalid. Lots of libraries have insufficient error handling that result in arcane issues for honest user errors.
Rather, the answer identifies the problem of the specific case (integers in the data) and the generally expected usage (only string data). This is a perfectly fitting resolution of the question.
Now, it might be improved a lot - experienced coders can pinpoint the error to every situation in which a string was expected but not supplied - but that goes well beyond what First Answer reviews have to bother with.
